# SNMP does not give any data

Tags: windows, snmp

I have installed SNMP.exe on windows 7 32 bit server. I have stopped SNMP trap and started only SNMP.exe. When i run SNMPWALK to get the windows server information, it says request timed out.....what could be the reason for it? Please help

Comment: Did you check windows firewall?

Comment: windows fire wall is disabled

Answer (score 1):

What does "installed SNMP.exe" **mean** ?

There is no such thing as "Windows 7 server"; you're referring to either Windows 7 (a desktop OS) or Windows Server 2008.

Both have a Windows service that offers SNMP functionality; install it from the Windows features screen.

You may have to adjust the community name, and trap and peer IP settings, to get it working.

Comment: Hi adaptr, yes it is windows 7, and i have installed SNMP from windows feature screen. I am using the community name as "public" and the listening port is 161. I am using snmpwalk tool to check the snmp output, but in the output screen it displays "Request timed out"